# Cordova (Phonegap): Deploy to Amazon FireOS

Tags: android, cordova

I followed the documentation in http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_amazonfireos_index.md.html

and tried to get the helloWorld (Cordova 3.3.1) deployed to an Kindle Fire HD (Version 7.4.6) over Eclipse.

I get the error:

> 02-20 14:36:29.392: E/CordovaActivity(11160): WebKit factory
>   initialization failed. Make sure you have android_interface.jar in
>   libs folder.

I made this from the docs:

```
 Add the awv_interface.jar from the downloaded SDK to  ~/.cordova/lib/amazon-fireos/cordova/3.1.0/libs/
```

and also tried to rename it to android_interface.jar, but it's not working too.

When I run it over the Terminal, i get the following error:

> Error: spawn EACCES
>       at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)

Has anybody made this work?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a permissions problem on the scripts inside the platforms/amazon-fireos/cordova/ directory which the main cordova command calls.

Do this to fix it for now, from your project's home directory:

```
chmod +x ./platforms/amazon-fireos/cordova/*
```

This will get it working by making these scripts executable on *nix systems like Mac OS X. (I work in this group at Amazon - I'll enter a bug on it so it's fixed properly.)

Comment: Thx. I can build now, but there is still the error with the android_interface.jar (as a Application error on my device): "Please copy android_interface.jar to apps libs folder and then rebuild the app."

Comment: @bqem There should be an error that displays on the first run, explaining that you need to download the AWV SDK from here: https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/IntegratingAWV.html and then install the awv_interface.jar into your ~/.cordova directory. If you need cross platform support, you also copy awv_android_factory.jar into your project folder under the amazon-fireos platform directory.