# Cordova support for Amazon FireTV ("android_interface.jar" error)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, amazon-fire-tv

I have used Cordova (3.4.x) to build the basic "Hello" and a custom HTML5 app for the Amazon Fire tablet. I saw a problem related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909987/cordova-phonegap-deploy-to-amazon-fireos) and resolved it per the answer from there (chmod +x on the build tools).

However, when I try to deploy the same apps ("Hello" and HTML5 app) to the **Amazon FireTV** device, I see this error:

> **Application Error**
>   AndroidWebKit classes are missing. Please copy 
>   android_interface.jar from AmazonWebView SDK to app's 
>   libs folder and the rebuild the app.

There is no file named "android_interface.jar" in the AmazonWebView SDK. I tried copying "awv_interface.jar" to the app's libs directory; no change. I also tried renaming awv_interface.jar to android_interface.jar; the app failed to compile.

Cordova's generic Android target will actually run on the FireTV; the "Hello" app works, but the five-way remote doesn't register on our HTML5 app, so I'd really rather use the amazon-fireos target.

Questions:

- Is Cordova's amazon-fireos target supposed to support Amazon FireTV?
- If not, will that support be added?
- Where can I find this "android_interface.jar" file?

Comment: this also happens when you run an application built with the amazon-fireos platform on an android device instead of a kindle. Luckily, Gene's answer is correct also in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Do not worry about renaming. You don't need to do that. Do these two things:

1) Put `awv_interface.jar` into `.cordova\lib\amazon-fireos\cordova\3.4.0\framework\libs`
   If libs doesn't exist, you need to create it.

2) Put `awv_android_factory.jar` into `<app-directory>\platforms\amazon-fireos\libs`

Take note that two are entirely different libs directories.

Rebuild the app. Then it will work.

Comment: Hello thanx for help, but i face one more error after this steps and my error is in "platforms/amazon-fireos/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java"  Error:(36, 33) error: package com.amazon.android.webkit does not exist . if you know about this then please tell me.